# I am trying to describe and initialize a 2 dimensional array in my main method

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO code application logic here
  int[][] array2D = new int [2][4];

  for (int i=0; i<array2D.length;i++){
    array2D[i]= new int [i+1];

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2D[i]));
```

Comment: You need nested for loops. One for the rows and the other for the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) to display your two-dimensional array. Assuming you want to initialize your arrays sequentially, you might use something like

```
int[][] array2D = new int[2][4];
for (int i = 0; i < array2D.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array2D[i].length; j++) {
        array2D[i][j] = (i * 4) + j + 1;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array2D));
```

**Or** skip the loops and *declare* and *initialize* your 2D array like

```
int[][] array2D = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 } };
```

Both of which output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```